# Using diacritic signs in c++

Tags: c++, diacritics

So I am trying to make a program for cesars cipher and I need to use diacritic letters like č ć š đ ž, in it. I need to work with them but c++ can't do that. Tried switching encoding but that didn't help.

`string letters[]={"a", "b", "c", "ć", "č", "d", "dž", "đ", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "lj", "m", "n", "nj", "o", "p", "r", "s", "š", "t", "u", "v", "z", "ž"};`

Comment: Try using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: Your code snippet is very small, and missing everything it needs to be a [mcve].  It worked for me, using C++, so I think C++ can do that.

Comment: Let's just say there's a for loop that prints all the letters, even that doesn't work. It prints out random letters `abc─ç─ìdd┼╛─æefghijklljmnnjoprs┼í`. I've tried switching to different encoding but no help there.